# What is this aromatic plant with narrow leaves and tiny white flowers that grows about 8' (2.5 m) high?

Tags: identification, weeds

[image]

Found in New York State, zone 7 where it has invaded my herb garden and outgrew it. I was wondering if it would be a useful herb.

Comment: When I crush it and smell it ranges in smell like at first I thought rosemary, but then I thought no maybe lavender, but then after another minute I was thinking peppermint? It has a stiff woody stem.

Comment: Is the steam rectangular or round? You cited species of Labiate (lamiaceae), which should have rectangular steam. Could you add also a photo of your garden? I fear it is Ambrosia (so an other family)

Comment: A photo of the plant in situ would be very useful too...